# How to retrieve count of records in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to retrieve the right count of records to mitigate an issue I am having. The below query returns 327 records from my database:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(at.someid) AS CountOfStudentsInTable FROM tblJobSkillAssessment AS at 
                INNER JOIN tblJobSkills j ON j.jobskillid = at.skillid
                LEFT JOIN tblStudentPersonal sp ON sp.someid2 = at.someid
                INNER JOIN tblStudentSchool ss ON ss.monsterid = at.someid
                INNER JOIN tblSchools s ON s.schoolid = ss.schoolid
                INNER JOIN tblSchoolDistricts sd ON sd.schoolid = s.schoolid
                INNER JOIN tblDistricts d ON d.districtid = sd.districtid
                INNER JOIN tblCountySchools cs ON cs.schoolid = s.schoolid
                INNER JOIN tblCounties cty ON cty.countyid = cs.countyid
                INNER JOIN tblRegionUserRegionGroups rurg ON rurg.districtid = d.districtid
                INNER JOIN tblGroups g ON g.groupid = rurg.groupid
                WHERE ss.graduationyear IN (SELECT Items FROM FN_Split(@gradyears, ',')) AND sp.optin = 'Yes' AND g.groupname = @groupname
```

Where I run into trouble is trying to reconcile that with the below query. One is for showing just a count of all the particular students the other is showing pertinent information for a set of students as needed but the total needs to be the same and it is not. The below query return 333 students - the reason is because the school the student goes to is in two separate counties and it counts that student twice. I can't figure out how to fix this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT @TableName AS TableName, d.district AS LocationName, cty.county AS County, COUNT(DISTINCT cc.monsterid) AS CountOfStudents, d.IRN AS IRN FROM tblJobSkillAssessment AS cc
            INNER JOIN tblJobSkills AS c ON c.jobskillid = cc.skillid
            INNER JOIN tblStudentPersonal sp ON sp.monsterid = cc.monsterid
            INNER JOIN tblStudentSchool ss ON ss.monsterid = cc.monsterid
            INNER JOIN tblSchools s ON s.schoolid = ss.schoolid
            INNER JOIN tblSchoolDistricts sd ON sd.schoolid = s.schoolid
            INNER JOIN tblDistricts d ON d.districtid = sd.districtid
            INNER JOIN tblCountySchools cs ON cs.schoolid = s.schoolid
            INNER JOIN tblCounties cty ON cty.countyid = cs.countyid
            INNER JOIN tblRegionUserRegionGroups rurg ON rurg.districtid = d.districtid
            INNER JOIN tblGroups g ON g.groupid = rurg.groupid
            WHERE ss.graduationyear IN (SELECT Items FROM FN_Split(@gradyears, ',')) AND sp.optin = 'Yes' AND g.groupname = @groupname
            GROUP BY cty.county, d.IRN, d.district
            ORDER BY LocationName ASC
```

Comment: How do you want to treat the students that are in two counties? Should they be a member of one county arbitrarily or is there a "primary" designation of some sort?

Comment: use `count(distinct at.someID)` instead? assuming at.SomeID is listed twice due to two different countries.  When distinct is added to a count it only looks at the column values being counted.  When applied at the onset it applies to all values of the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the count, then perhaps `count(distinct)` will solve the problem:

```
select count(distinct at.someid)
```

I don't see what `at.someid` refers to, so perhaps:

```
select count(distinct cc.monsterid)
```

Comment: the distinct can even not be necessary you just count on the students table (do you rellay all that joins?) and you can guarantee there are one row/students (if not you data is not well persisted) the "multiplication" is done by the joins

Comment: @jean . . . Some of the joins are necessary because of the `where` clause, but it doesn't seem that all are.